# What's the purpose of torch.autograd.Variable?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I load `features` and `labels` from my training dataset. Both of them are originally numpy arrays, but I change them to the torch tensor using `torch.from _numpy(features.copy())` and `torch.tensor(labels.astype(np.bool))`.

And I notice that `torch.autograd.Variable` is something like `placeholder` in `tensorflow`.

When I train my network, first I tried

```py
features = features.cuda()
labels = labels.cuda()

outputs = Config.MODEL(features)
loss = Config.LOSS(outputs, labels)
```

Then I tried

```py
features = features.cuda()
labels = labels.cuda()

input_var = Variable(features)
target_var = Variable(labels)
outputs = Config.MODEL(input_var)
loss = Config.LOSS(outputs, target_var)
```

Both blocks succeed in activating training, but I worried that there might be trivial difference.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

<strike>According to [this question](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-a-Tensor-and-a-Variable-in-Pytorch) you no longer need variables to use Pytorch Autograd.</strike>

Thanks to @skytree, we can make this even more explizit: [Variables have been deprecated](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html), i.e. you're not supposed to use them anymore.

> Autograd automatically supports Tensors with `requires_grad` set to `True`.

And more importantly

> `Variable(tensor)` and `Variable(tensor, requires_grad)` still work as expected, but they return Tensors instead of Variables.

This means that if your `features` and `labels` are tensors already (which they seem to be in your example) your `Variable(features)` and `Variable(labels)` does only return a tensor again.

The original purpose of Variables was to be able to use automatic differentiation ([Source](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/what-is-the-difference-between-tensors-and-variables-in-pytorch/4914)):

> Variables are just wrappers for the tensors so you can now easily auto compute the gradients.

Comment: The Variable API has been deprecated. https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html

Comment: Well, I kind of said that in my first sentence. But I will edit my answer to make it clearer.